# If statement not working with access level php mysql

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I've searched so much about what i maight be doing wrong but i've failed to get an if statemnt to give me the results that i want. This is not the first time I am working with if statements but this seems to be a challenge. Ok, I want to hide part of a `<li>` list item according to user access level but i don't seem to get it to work as expected. my access levels are 1 for normal users and 2 for admin

`

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#MyBookings" title="My Bookings">My Items</a></li>
    <li><a href="#MyReviews" title="My Reviews">Submit Item</a></li>
    <?php if($_SESSION['privillages'] = '2'){ ?>
       <li><a href="#Incomings" title="Incomings">Incoming Items  </a> </li>
    <?php }else{?>
    <?php } ?>
    <li><a href="#MySettings" title="Settings">Account Settings</a></li>
</ul>`
```

Thats the code snippet for the `<ul>`. When i remove the 2 in the qoutes, the `<li>` shows, when i put it there, the `<li>` goes

And this is the code that handles user login

```
public function login( array $data )
    {
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = false;
        if( !empty( $data ) ){

            // Trim all the incoming data:
            $trimmed_data = array_map('trim', $data);

            // escape variables for security
            $email = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con,  $trimmed_data['email'] );
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con,  $trimmed_data['password'] );

            if((!$email) || (!$password) ) {
                throw new Exception( LOGIN_FIELDS_MISSING );
            }
            $password = md5( $password );
            $query = "SELECT user_id, name, email, created, privillages FROM users where email = '$email' and password = '$password' ";
            $result = mysqli_query($this->_con, $query);
            $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            mysqli_close($this->_con);
            if( $count == 1){
                $_SESSION = $data;
                $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
                return true;
            }else{
                throw new Exception( LOGIN_FAIL );
            }
        } else{
            throw new Exception( LOGIN_FIELDS_MISSING );
        }
    }
```

What am i doing wrong here

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution finally, i was missing double equal signs to justify my data from my database, here is my edited code for the `<ul>`

```
<ul>
                            <li><a href="#MyBookings" title="My Bookings">My Items</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#MyReviews" title="My Reviews">Submit Item</a></li>


              <?php if($_SESSION['privillages'] == '2'){ ?>
<li><a href="#Incomings" title="Incomings">Incoming Items  </a> </li>
                           <?php }else{?>

                           <?php } ?>
                           <li><a href="#MySettings" title="Settings">Account Settings</a></li>
                        </ul>`
```